# Cognito metrics not showing in Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

Been trying to setup Cognito/Pinpoint integration to get metrics on user sign in and sessions, following the developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html. So far, no metrics are being reported on the Pinpoint console.

Cognito login has been working fine, and users can login/logout successfully. The actual authentication to Cognito is done server-side with tokens being passed back to the device.

Does there need to be some server-side integration with Pinpoint? Or does login need to be done on device through the mobile sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears login must be done on device through the AWS Mobile SDK (or AWS Amplify). When I added client-side login it was reflected on Pinpoint very quickly.